# how to populate Datagridview each row from specific sql query?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

Working c# ,want to fill datagridview for each row sql query is different ,Given a button to add the row ,so sql query is user specific.But not find way ,join query not worked because after 1st query filled the datagridview ,when next query complete datagridview data refresh.
As performance wise ,what is economical either direct query from sql for each row or get the table as datatable once and query from that table to populate datagridview?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diuIK.png)

Comment: Can you share the different query examples?

Comment: From a performance point of view it is always better to minimize the number of database requests.

Comment: Date : from date picker & Name-From Text ,by click add button query to db as select * from dbtbl where name =xyz and date=xx/xx/2018 ,load the result in row 1 of datagridview ,then if again user can give new date and time again new query & result will display in row 2 of datagridview.